# Finding the number of 2014th degree polynomials formed from a solution set of {1,2,3}

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

How many polynomials $$x^{2014} + a_{2013} x^{2013} + a_{2012} x^{2012} + ... + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$$ with real coefficients $$a_0 , a_1 , ... , a_{2013}$$ can be formed, if all its zeros are real and can only come from the set {1,2,3}.

I tried using conbinations--choosing 2 out of 3, then choosing 3 out of 3; until I realized my idea was wrong. Next, I tried looking for a pattern: I listed all the combinations for a second degree polynomial and I got 6 combinations, I also did it for a third degree polynomial and I got 10 polynomials. However, I have know idea how to continue from here on.

Honestly, I already know the answer. I peeked at the answer from the back of the questionnaire. However, it does not explain why. I wish to understand how to answer this kind of problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can someone please explain what Leox suggested? I honestly do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The polynomial can be factorized in the way 
$$
(x-1)^a (x-2)^b (x-3)^c,
$$
where $a+b+c=2014.$

Now you should find the number of integer solutions of the equation $a+b+c=2014.$  You may use the generating function for the number of integer solutions of the equation $a+b+c=n.$  So, we have the answer
$$
[z^{2014}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}=\binom{2014+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{2016}{2}=2031120.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Leox. However, I am very sorry for I still do not know how to proceed even with your hint. Perhaps, one more clue?

Comment: Please elaborate your hint a bit more. I still do not know how to proceed. I really want to understand this problem.

Comment: This makes it a classic [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem

Comment: @ Carl Terence Valdellon  I add some text

Comment: @Leox Honestly, when you mentioned generating functions, it confused me more than it helped. But when I considered using stars and bars ofRoss Millikan, and applied your earlier hint, Leox, it made perfect sense! Thank you very much, guys.

Comment: OK, the easy way. It is well know that the number of integer solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=m$ equals $\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$, Now just put $n=3, m=2014.$

Comment: @ Leox Thank you very much for your help.